# Passing inline temporary class in c++ needs to be const. How to work around this

Tags: c++, c++11, temporary-objects

I want to write portable code in c++11 for different CPU's (actually MCU's). As some CPU's does not support reading program data directly through it's memory address space (such as Atmel AVR), I need a solution that calls a function either with a direct address, or with a custom made Stream pointer to read the data trough some external storage.

Consider this code as the custom library:

```
class IStream
{
    public: virtual char ReadChar();
};

class ConstMemoryStream : public IStream
{
    const char* Position;

    public: ConstMemoryStream(const char* startAddress)
    {
        Position = startAddress;
    }

    public: char ReadChar() override
    {
        return *Position++;
    }
};

void Send(char data) { } // Send data to serial port
```

Now, I want to implement a function that takes either a memory address, or a Stream to read the data from:

```
// const parameter is needed here, otherwise error: invalid initialisation of non-const reference of type 'IStream&' from an rvalue of type 'IStream'
void PrintMessage(const IStream& stream)
{
    while (true) // TODO: end condition
        //Send(stream.ReadChar());  // this gives an error because i need to use a const parameter: passing 'const IStream' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers
        Send( ((IStream*)&stream)->ReadChar() );  // this works, this actually bypass the error above. IS THIS OK?????
}

void PrintMessage(char* address); // overload to use memory instead of stream. implementation not important here
```

Next, I want to call PrintMessage with a Stream, but this stream needs to be created inline, and is not needed anymore outside the PrintMessage function:

```
int main(void)
{
    // Requirement: ConstMemoryStream needs to be created and passed INLINE PrintMessage
    PrintMessage(ConstMemoryStream("Hello!")); // This works only if i put const in PrintMessage parameter.
}
```

All the code above compiles and works, but my main concern is that I need to use a const parameter in the PrintMessage function (otherwise I get an error). Because of this, I need to do an ugly cast:

```
Send( ((IStream*)&stream)->ReadChar() );
```

This basically makes the parameter non-const to avoid the error. But is there a better solution to do this "legally"?

The stream instance itself cannot be const because it advances it's position internally, but c++ requires to pass it as const because it's an inline temporary variable which is always considered as an rvalue.

I don't see any harm from a temporary variable to modify itself, after the PrintMessage function return it's discarded anyway.

The inline requireWhat I finally want to do is this:

```
#ifdef CPU_AVR
    #define CSTR(str) ConstMemoryStream(PROGMEM str) // the PROGMEM attribute puts the text in a separate space not accessible in regular memory
#elif defined CPU_SAM
    #define CSTR(str) (char*)str
#endif

int main2(void)
{
    // If the CPU does not support direct address mapping to it's FLASH space, pass a stream instead of a direct memory pointer
    PrintMessage(CSTR("Hello"));
}
```

Any idea on how to do this properly without casting to discard the error? Or is the current code above acceptable?

Comment: Does your compiler support C++11, or later?

Comment: Yes, it's C++11 (updated my question)

Comment: "const IStream& stream" why you make it const? simply take a ref and everything works fine. This is not related to AVR as on my knowledge STL is not available for AVR. If you have a STL for AVR, let me know!

Comment: @anastaciu: the string itself is const, but the stream that reads the const string is not const, which is allowed. My question is not about dropping const from the string, but from the stream.

Comment: @Bigjim, Sam's answer seems to solve your problem, does it not?

Comment: @Bigjim, of course you'll need to keep the const qualifiers in order to correctly pass a string like that.

Comment: @anastaciu Indeed, && is the perfect solution. Just tried and compiles without errors or warnings

Comment: @Bigjim yes, you could also pass a constructed object as a parameter, but this is better because it solves the potencial scope and ownership issues.

Comment: @anastaciu Indeed, passing a constructed object was not an option because I need to use it inline with a macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With C++11 you can simply take an rvalue reference as a parameter.

```
void PrintMessage(IStream && stream)
```

rvalue references will bind to temporaries, and will mostly be indistinguishable from lvalue references, in this context.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Either your interface is wrong, or your usage is wrong. Currently you are `const_cast`ing your stream. If you ever pass a `const` IStream object, that would be undefined behaviour.

Either:

```
class IStream
{
    public: virtual char ReadChar() const;
};
```

Or:

```
void PrintMessage(IStream& stream)
{
    while (true) // TODO: end condition
        Send(stream.ReadChar());  
}

void PrintMessage(IStream&& stream)
{
    while (true) // TODO: end condition
        Send(stream.ReadChar());  
}

int main(void)
{
    PrintMessage(ConstMemoryStream("Hello!")); 
}
```

Comment: Indeed, I know my usage was wrong, that was the reason for my question (how to do it right). IStream&& is the solution, as in your second example. Thx!